# timestamp does not change in requestAnimationFrame callback

Tags: javascript, for-loop, requestanimationframe

i want keep a trace of timestamp in two manners, first i forloop the call, second with a setinterval.
But with the forloop, the timestamp is the same in all the times[] array ???

```
var i = 0;
var i2=0;
var times = [];
var times2 = [];

function step(timestamp) {
   times[i++] = timestamp;
}

for (let k=1 ; k < 1111 ; k++) requestAnimationFrame(step);


function step2(timestamp) {times2[i2++] = timestamp;}

rAF = _ => requestAnimationFrame(step2);
const ID = setInterval(rAF,0);
setTimeout( _ => clearInterval(ID) , 200);

console.log(times); // [22.453 , 22.453 , 22.453 ,......] NEVER CHANGE !
console.log(times2); // [ 87.456 , 87.456 , 99.223 ...]
```

EDIT : following change does not affect times[], always same value

```
for (let k=1 ; k < 1111 ; k++) {
    for (let o=1 ; o < 11111111 ; o++) {} // i guess it put some delay between each call to requestAnimationFrame
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for (let k=1 ; k < 1111 ; k++) requestAnimationFrame(step);` calls all `requestAnimationFrame` at the same time, so all `1110` calls to `step` are scheduled for the next animation frame, and so they are called all at the same time.

This would be a setup to run `step` function for each animation frame for 1111 times.

```
function step(timestamp) {
   times[i++] = timestamp;
   if( i < 1111 ) {
      requestAnimationFrame(step)
   }
}

requestAnimationFrame(step)
```

Changing:

```
for (let k=1 ; k < 1111 ; k++) {
   requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

to:

```
for (let k=1 ; k < 1111 ; k++) {
    for (let o=1 ; o < 11111111 ; o++) {} // i guess it put some delay between each call to requestAnimationFrame
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

does not change anything, it does not matter how long the loop takes. JavaScript is single threaded. As of that while the loop is running, no other code will be executed in between. So all  `requestAnimationFrame(step);` within the loop will always be queued up for the same next animation frame.

Comment: ok but why calls to step are called all at the same time ? for (let k=1 ; k < 1111 ; k++) { 
 do_some_stuff(); requestAnimationFrame(step); }

Comment: @PhilippeOceangermanique If you call `requestAnimationFrame`, then only thing that happens is that the function you pass to `requestAnimationFrame` is added to a list, and on the next animation frame the javascript engine call all function in this list. And the next animation frame will happen some time after your current code execution ends.

Comment: @PhilippeOceangermanique [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval): `delay [...] If this parameter is less than 10, a value of 10 is used. Note that the actual delay may be longer`. So you set a interval that is called every 10+ milliseconds, and when it is called it registers a a callback that should be executed on the next animation frame. 30fps are ~33ms per frame, so about ~2-3 interval callbacks happen before each next animation frame. that why ~2-3 `step2` have the same time.